# Unable to vertically align text inside container

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align text in a couple of containers using `line-height`, but it just won't work. I have never had any problems with it before, but for some reason it just won't line up properly now.

Now, I'm probably just blind from all the coding, but I just can't seem to find where the problem lies...

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="formLabel">
    <div class="labelNumber">D</div>
    <div class="labelTitle">
        <h2>New Password</h2>
        <p>Check Help for character and length restrictions</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is how my CSS looks like:

```
.formLabel
{
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

.labelNumber
{
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #191919;
    font: bold 18px Arial;
    color: #555555;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

It's the character in the `.labelNumber` container that I'm trying to vertically align.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line-height attribute is part of the shorthand `font` syntax, so put the line-height after it or integrate it into the font attribute.

```
.labelNumber {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #191919;
  font: bold 18px/30px Arial; /** Font-size / Line-height */
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Basically the font attribute was overwriting the line-height.

Comment: Oh my god, can't believe I didn't catch that.. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: There is also the `!important` rule, but Tom has the right idea.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your current code is that the order of your CSS declarations is forcing the browser to forget about the `line-height: 30px;` declaration, since after it you're using the `font` short-hand syntax `font: bold 18px Arial;`.

**You can solve your issue with one of two options:**

- Move the `line-height: 30px;` to after the `font: bold 18px Arial;`:

  See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/nz7fU/12/) Example.

  ```
  .labelNumber {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #191919;
    font: bold 18px Arial;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #555555;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  ```
- Loose the `line-height: 30px;` and update the `font` short-hand to `font: bold 18px/30px Arial;`:

  See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/nz7fU/13/) Example.

  ```
  .labelNumber {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #191919;
    font: bold 18px/30px Arial;
    color: #555555;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  ```

You can read about the `font` short-hand syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font).

**As a side note:** For the purpose of code reduction, the second option is the preferred one.